# How to fetch value of checkbox in oracle apex if I used a blank form?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

[image][image]I want to put the value of checked name from a checkbox in oracle apex into a table, but unable to do that.
I tried taking help from google but the steps mentioned didn't work too.
Could you please advise how to do that if I have taken a blank form and then added a checkbox to it, also I fetched the checkbox value from LOV.

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried?

Comment: Please provide more information: which items do you have, what did you do, which kinds of processes, your code, etc. All what is needed to reproduce error.

Comment: I have added a checkbox with a name: 'P12_NEW'. This checkbox contains a list of users.
There is one textbox on the top to enter the amount manually.
I want that amount to appear in front of each user which I mark as checked "in a table named:'usr_amt' after I click save button".

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you are using a List of Values as a source of your checkboxes. Let's say you have following values there:

```
return value   display value
----------------------------
         123   andAND
         456   Dibya
         789   Anshul
         321   aafirst
         555   Anuj
```

When you select several values, APEX puts their return values into a string and separate them with `:`. So for the case in your screenshot the value in item `P12_NEW` will be `123:555`. To split this values you can use the following query:

```
 select regexp_substr(:P12_NEW, '[^:]+', 1, level) values
   from dual
connect by regexp_substr(:P12_NEW, '[^:]+', 1, level) is not null
```

The result will be:

```
values
------
   123
   555
```

Next, you need to put these values into table `usr_amt` (let's say with columns `user_id` and `amount`, and the amount is entered into item `P12_AMOUNT`):

```
merge into usr_amt t
using (select regexp_substr(:P12_NEW, '[^:]+', 1, level) user_id
         from dual
      connect by regexp_substr(:P12_NEW, '[^:]+', 1, level) is not null
       ) n on (n.user_id = t.user_id)
 when matched then update
  set t.amount = :P12_AMOUNT
 when not matched then insert (user_id, amount)
      values (n.user_id, :P12_AMOUNT)
```

This query will search for the each `user_id` selected in the table, and if the user presents there, updates the corresponding value to the value of item `:P12_AMOUNT`, if not present - inserts a row with `user_id` and the value.

Comment: DO I need to put below query too in the form, if yes please advice where to put this:
 `select regexp_substr(:P12_NEW, '[^:]+', 1, level) values
   from dual
connect by regexp_substr(:P12_NEW, '[^:]+', 1, level) is not null`

Comment: No, this query is just to demonstrate the idea, `MERGE` is enough.

Comment: I tried but merge is not working, please suggest if I can do screen share so that you get better idea if I am missing something...

Comment: There could be plenty of reasons, describe how do you do this and which error (if any) do you see. Probably, it is better to create a new question.

Comment: Many thanks for the help and time on this, I will create different question if required.